# UWP Send Image to Whatsapp

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app, whatsapp, uwp-xaml

Currently, I had tried to develop an app that can send an image to Whatsapp but I saw a lot of solution only share Text only.

As I known Windows Phone 8.1/Windows 8.1 are using Data Transfer Manager.

May I ask about is that any ways to share an image to Whatsapp in UWP or Better solution?

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use share contract for sending message to WhatsApp, then I can recommend you this example:
[How to share an image](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh871370.aspx)

What about API, I have found only this article:
[WhatsApp cofounder: Sorry developers, no API for you](http://mashable.com/2015/03/25/whatsapp-developers-api/#7N.QcLXt5Sqa)